# How to obtain deg instead ° with siunitx package?

Tags: siunitx, unit-of-measure, degrees

I'm using the following command to write a phisical quantity in my report:

```
\si[per-mode = symbol]{\degree\per\second
```

I obtain: °/s but I want: deg/s.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You can use `\deg` instead.
You can choose to use `/` instead of `^{-1}` for 'per' with the option `[per-mode=symbol]` which you can make a package option, as in `\usepackage[per-mode=symbol]{siunitx}` or pass to a single call of `\SI` or `\si`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \SI{1}{\deg\per\second}
    \SI[per-mode=symbol]{1}{\deg\per\second}
\end{document}
```

If you want to redefine `\degree` across the document you can use

```
\DeclareSIUnit{\degree}{deg}
```

in your preamble.

Comment: Note that simple strings are also allowed, `\SI[per-mode = symbol]{1}{deg\per\second}` or `\SI[per-mode = symbol]{1}{xyz\per\second}` works ok as well.